# Can't get rid of red validation border around listbox control (IDataErrorInfo)

Tags: c#, wpf, idataerrorinfo

I have removed red border from styling properties but it still remains on listbox, how can I fix this?
[image]

As you can see no red border is this a default thing?

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="eTemplate">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding ElementName=adorned,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" >
                </TextBlock>
                <Border BorderThickness="0">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorned"/>
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

.

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" Margin="449,275,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Name="LocationTo" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.SelectedIndex>
            <Binding Path="LocationTo" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
        </ListBox.SelectedIndex>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Conn Junction"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Multhy Pass"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Suddean Halt"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="End Terminal"/>
    </ListBox>
```

.

```
<TextBox Height="27" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=eTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,62,0,0" Name="FName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" FontSize="12" TextChanged="FName_TextChanged">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="FName" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
```

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between your title and your question?

Comment: @Steve I've removed red border from styling properties for validation as you can see in the image the red border still remains on listbox I've also added some code for you to look at.

Comment: @HenkHolterman edited

Comment: @HenkHolterman edited

Comment: @HenkHolterman  edited